# jQuery Combining toggle(), show() and hide()

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui

I have this working exactly like I want (see the Fiddle below) except I discovered that toggle() was deprecated. I'm wondering if I could use toggleClass() or hide() and show() to toggle the visibility of the dropdownpanel.

```js
$("#dropdown").click(function() {
  $("#dropdownpanel").toggle();
});

$("#latinlink").click(function() {
    $("#sometext").hide();
    $("#latin").show();
});

$("#back").click(function() {
    $("#latin").hide();
    $("#sometext").show();
});
```

```css
#dropdownpanel {
  width: 236px;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(00, 00, 00, 0.55);
  color: #ffffff;
  position: fixed;
  top: 38px;
  left: 0px;
  display: none;
  padding: 5px;
}

#latin {
  width: 236px;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(00, 00, 00, 0.55);
  color: #ffffff;
  position: fixed;
  top: 38px;
  left: 0px;
  display: none;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <button id="dropdown">
      Dropdown
    </button>
    
    <div id="dropdownpanel">
      <p id="sometext">Click
        <a href="#" id="latinlink">here</a> to read some latin...
      </p>
    </div>
    
    <div id="latin">
  <button id="back">
    Back
  </button>
      <br /> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, epicuri argumentum constituam eum ea. Munere aliquip te nec, at nec dicat fuisset offendit, quo an sonet honestatis. Tempor facete sadipscing te his. Nam vivendo postulant reprehendunt te, offendit principes pri ex, at causae
      oblique torquatos pro.
      <br />
      <br /> Libris philosophia has eu, nam iriure alienum intellegam at. Nec appareat electram ne, amet nonumes per te. Usu eu nisl verterem, labore regione legimus in nam, vel saperet laboramus voluptatibus ut. Ad eam altera nemore. No nobis corpora pro, qui
      ex tale suas dissentias, et iisque omittam inciderint sit. Usu ut case menandri vituperata.
    </div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sayzawn/4b6wwsx7/)

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. And what does _"It is currently behaving like the back button"_ mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current behaviour is because when you click the `#latinlink` element it hides the `#dropdownpanel`, so then when you click the `#dropdown` button again it toggles `#dropdownpanel` from hidden to visible again, which is the same as what the `#back` button does.

The easiest way to fix that without changing the HTML at all is probably to update the `#dropdown` click handler to test whether `#latin` is currently visible:

```js
$("#dropdown").click(function() {
  if ($("#latin").is(":visible"))
    $("#dropdownpanel").hide();
  else
    $("#dropdownpanel").toggle();
  $("#latin").hide();
});
    
$("#latinlink").click(function() {
  $("#dropdownpanel").hide();
  $("#latin").show();
});
    
$("#back").click(function() {
  $("#latin").hide();
  $("#dropdownpanel").show();
});
```

```css
#dropdownpanel, #latin {
      width: 236px;
      height: 100vh;
      background: rgba(00, 00, 00, 0.55);
      color: #ffffff;
      position: fixed;
      top: 38px;
      left: 0px;
      display: none;
      padding: 5px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <button id="dropdown">
      Dropdown
    </button>
    
    <div id="dropdownpanel">
      <p>Click
        <a href="#" id="latinlink">here</a> to read some latin...
      </p>
    </div>
    
    <div id="latin">
      <button id="back">
        Back
      </button>
      <br /> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, epicuri argumentum constituam eum ea. Munere aliquip te nec, at nec dicat fuisset offendit, quo an sonet honestatis. Tempor facete sadipscing te his. Nam vivendo postulant reprehendunt te, offendit principes pri ex, at causae
      oblique torquatos pro.
      <br />
      <br /> Libris philosophia has eu, nam iriure alienum intellegam at. Nec appareat electram ne, amet nonumes per te. Usu eu nisl verterem, labore regione legimus in nam, vel saperet laboramus voluptatibus ut. Ad eam altera nemore. No nobis corpora pro, qui
      ex tale suas dissentias, et iisque omittam inciderint sit. Usu ut case menandri vituperata.
    </div>
```

Alternatively you might change the HTML structure to put the `#latin` div inside the `#dropdownpanel`.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. However, I noticed something new. The `#dropdown` button only opens the `#dropdownpanel` div. How would I require it to open whichever div was previously open?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise that you wanted that behaviour. I think it would be a lot simpler to put another div around both of your current divs, and have the existing #dropdown button toggle the visibility of the new container div without changing the visibility of the inner divs - that way whichever inner div was previously visible would still be visible. Your existing #latinlink and #back click handlers would work as is.

Answer (score 0):

i added wrapper for `#dropdownpanel` and `#latin`. Reference here [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/verstalo/d8uvLqft/6/) and moved styles from `#dropdownpanel` to `#dropdowncontent`

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the button was toggling an element that was not visible.

```js
$("#dropdown").click(function() {
 if ($('#dropdownpanel').is(':visible')) {
  $("#dropdownpanel").hide();
 } else if ($('#latin').is(':visible')) {
  $("#latin").hide();
 } else {
  $("#dropdownpanel").show();
 }
});
$("#latinlink").click(function() {
 $("#dropdownpanel").hide();
 $("#latin").show();
});
$("#back").click(function() {
 $("#latin").hide();
 $("#dropdownpanel").show();
});
```

```css
#dropdownpanel {
  width: 236px;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(00, 00, 00, 0.55);
  color: #ffffff;
  position: fixed;
  top: 38px;
  left: 0px;
  display: none;
  padding: 5px;
}

#latin {
  width: 236px;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(00, 00, 00, 0.55);
  color: #ffffff;
  position: fixed;
  top: 38px;
  left: 0px;
  display: none;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="dropdown">Dropdown</button>
<div id="dropdownpanel">
  <p>Click <button id="latinlink">here</button> to read some latin...</p>
</div>
<div id="latin">
  <button id="back">Back</button><br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, modo vitae latine id sea, ea illud facilis definitiones cum. Ei mea ignota iuvaret, debet verear adipiscing no mel, mel gubergren torquatos temporibus ex. Mei nemore mandamus et. Omnes
  legimus principes pri et.<br>
  <br> Nam eu odio facer cotidieque, cum in reque elitr fastidii. An duo hinc iisque principes, nostro mollis laoreet cu ius. No mel habeo soluta repudiare, ex qui tritani apeirian delicatissimi. Eos ei dolore option definitiones, ad sit liber scaevola
  dissentiet.
</div>
```